# Why is the font different for res.end and res.send?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following minimal basic express node js application:

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express ();

app.get ('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send ('Hello');
});

app.listen (3000);
```

When I access this site on localhost:3000 I get a response that looks like:

[image: res-send]

If I change `res.send ('Hello');` to `res.end ('Hello');`, the response is a different font like:

[image: res-end]

I am curious; why the difference?

Comment: It's most likely a difference in the `Content-Type` header that is causing your browser to render it differently. For example, `application/json` is often rendered by browsers in monospace font. Check the headers.

Comment: thanks, I confirmed they're text/html for `send` and text/plain for `end`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you pass a string to `res.send()`, it [automatically assumes a Content-Type of html](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L109).

`res.end()`, however, simply calls node's underlying `end()` implementation on the response stream, so no assumptions are made for the Content-Type.

The reason it renders differently is simply a browser decision to render a "pretty" default font for HTML, and a less-styled font for unknown content types.