# What is the difference between res.end() and res.send()?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a beginner in `Express.js` and I'm confused by these two keywords: `res.end()` and `res.send()`.

Are they the same or different?

Comment: I think `res.end` used by plain node where as `res.send` is used by express framwork

Comment: `response.send` includes a `response.end` call.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

First of all, `res.send()` and `res.end()` are **different**.

`res.send()` will send the HTTP response. Its syntax is,

```
res.send([body])
```

The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array. For example:

```
res.send(new Buffer('whoop'));
res.send({ some: 'json' });
res.send('<p>some html</p>');
res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!');
res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' });
```

See [this](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) for more info.

`res.end()` will end the response process. This method actually comes from Node core, specifically the `response.end()` method of `http.ServerResponse`. It is used to quickly end the response without any data. For example:

```
res.end();
res.status(404).end();
```

Read [this](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) for more info.

Comment: But res.end can actually act like res.send, in that you can pass a string argument to add as the response body. On top of that, res.send also ends the response. So how are they functionally different?

Comment: @psytech140 Jmar77 had a nice response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22774872/5177017):
 
"If you pass a string to res.send(), it automatically assumes a Content-Type of html. 

res.end(), however, simply calls node's underlying end() implementation on the response stream, so no assumptions are made for the Content-Type."

Comment: Had to upvote this purely because I've never used `express` but from the title thought - one sends something, one ends something.... 'twas right.

Comment: But what if you just use `res.send()` with nothing. Does this act like `res.end()`?

Comment: See the difference at [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49242271/2273211) and [what happened under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54874227/2273211)

Comment: **Downvoted as it’s misleading.** “`.end()` will end the response process.” Yes, and so does `.send()`. You phrased as if it doesn’t.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes. To be precise, [`response.send()` calls `response.end(undefined, undefined)`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/8368dc178af16b91b576c4c1d135f701a0007e5d/lib/response.js#L227-L236), which is equivalent to `response.end()`.

Answer (score 293):

First of all, `res.send()` and `res.end()` are **not** the same.

I would like to make a little bit more emphasis on some key differences between `res.end()` & `res.send()` with respect to response headers and why they are important.

***1. res.send() will check the structure of your output and set header
information accordingly.***

---

```
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
       res.send('<b>hello</b>');
    });
```

[image]

---

```
     app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
         res.send({msg:'hello'});
     });
```

[image]

Where with res.end() you can only respond with text and it will not set "*Content-Type*"

```
      app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
           res.end('<b>hello</b>');
      });
```

[image]

***2. res.send() will set "ETag" attribute in the response header***

```
      app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
            res.send('<b>hello</b>');
      });
```

[image]

*Why is this tag important?*
The ETag HTTP response header is an identifier for a specific version of a resource. It allows caches to be more efficient, and saves bandwidth, as a web server does not need to send a full response if the content has not changed.

*`res.end()` will NOT set this header attribute*

Comment: This shall be accepted answer in my opinion... more amphasis is made on actual differences that can ruin your work day instead of discussion on ending response with/without content...

Comment: So basically consider `.end()` as a low-level function and use `.send()` in your Express application?

Comment: Kept it Simple & Silly :) +1

Comment: @EricBurel Yes. `.send` calls `.end` internally.

Comment: this part of the answer is wrong: `Where with res.end() you can only respond with text`. res.send() internally uses `res.setHeader("content-type", myContentType)` to set the content-type and then sends the data using `res.end(data...)`. `res.end()` can send all kind of data, not just text

Answer (score 63):

`res.send()` implements `res.write`, `res.setHeaders` and `res.end`:

1. It checks the data you send and sets the correct response headers.
2. Then it streams the data with `res.write`.
3. Finally, it uses `res.end` to set the end of the request.

There are some cases in which you will want to do this manually, for example, if you want to stream a file or a large data set. In these cases, you will want to set the headers yourself and use `res.write` to keep the stream flow.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the excellent answers, I would like to emphasize here, when to use *res.end()* and when to use *res.send()* this was why I originally landed here and I didn't found a solution.

The answer is very simple.

*res.end()* is used to quickly end the response without sending any data.

An example for this would be starting a process on a server:

```
app.get('/start-service', (req, res) => {
   // Some logic here
   exec('./application'); // dummy code
   res.end();
});
```

If you would like to send data in your response then you should use *res.send()* instead:

```
app.get('/start-service', (req, res) => {
   res.send('{"age":22}');
});
```

Here you can read more:

- http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end
- http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send

Answer (score 7):

`res.send()` is used to send the response to the client where `res.end()` is used to end the response you are sending.

`res.send()` automatically call `res.end()` So you don't have to call or mention it after `res.send()`

Answer (score 5):

`res` is an HttpResponse object which extends from OutgoingMessage. `res.send` calls `res.end` which is implemented by OutgoingMessage to send HTTP response and close connection. We see code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ff1dbeb73732b6aae73f8df407e3bb423ccc3b7/lib/response.js#L221)