# How response.end and response.send differs?

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I am trying to build a simple application using express js. I am new to node and express js. Can somebody explain the difference in response.end and response.send

I tried this command and both sent the request(message) to the Server.

```
res.send('Send the message');
res.end('send the message');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between res.end() and res.send()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555290/what-is-the-difference-between-res-end-and-res-send)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.send()` is a method built into *express*, and will make it [automatically assume a Content-Type of html](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L145).

`res.end()`, on the other hand, just uses the underlying `end()` implementation built into nodejs on the response stream (aka. not express), so it doesn't attempt to assume the `Content-Type`.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Thanks!