# Express nodejs router always on dealing

Tags: node.js, express

In my app.js, I definite a search router

```
app.use('/search', require('./router/search'))
```

In the search.js files, what I do is request a website and response website data, but the router always on dealing.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express()
const url = require('url')
const http = require('http')

router.get('/', searchHandler)

function searchHandler(req, res) {
    request('http://baidu.com', 'get')
        .then(result => {
            res.end(result)
        })
}

function request(link, method, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        link = url.parse(link)
        const result = '';
        const options = {
            hostname: link.hostname,
            port: 80,
            path: link.path,
            method: method
        }
        http.request(options, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                result += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                resolve(result)
            })
            req.on('error', function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        })
    })
}

module.exports = router
```

why does my `res.end(result)` not works?

Comment: You probably want `res.send`, not `res.end`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between res.end() and res.send()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555290/what-is-the-difference-between-res-end-and-res-send)

Comment: Neither of those explain why `res.end(result)` doesn't also work, since it appears from the doc that it should.

Comment: Do you get anything if you put `console.log()` immediately before `request()` is called or inside the `then()` block?

Comment: It seems that I that I don't end http request. 

```javascript
const http_client = http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk)
        result.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        resolve(result.toString())
    })
    
})
http_client.on('error', function (err) {
    reject(err);
}); 
http_client.end()
```
   
it works