# when use req.end it prints two times in console. why?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js

what is the use of `req.end` in Node.js .I use that but ,it print two times

```
app.use('/',function(req,res){
  res.send("hello world");  //send to browser
  console.log("by");  //print in console
  req.end;     //req is end here
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: `req.end` or `res.end` ?

Comment: i use only req.end

Comment: Your Using Express ? There is no function like [req.end](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)

Comment: For More details about res.send and res.end https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555290/what-is-the-difference-between-res-end-and-res-send

Comment: change to res.end(). but still it can show in console like                               G:\login & registation>node demo
i am the middle
hello
world
i am the middle
hello
world

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use('/',function(req,res){
  res.send("hello world");  //send to browser
  console.log("by");  //print in console
  req.end;     //req is end here
}).listen(3000);
```

In the above code when you hit localhost:3000/ from your browser, browser hit two requests at the same time one for favicon and one for '/ ' endpoint and you create only '/' router then all request will catch in '/' route.
when you hit this endpoint from postman it will print one time in the console.

[image]

Comment: solved the problem and get some knowledge on req,res