# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. TRYING TO SEND DATA USINIG HTTP

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, sqlite

I am getting the following error

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:264:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at Statement. (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/app.js:95:17)
--> in Database#all('SELECT * FROM users WHERE julianday(?) <= julianday(time) AND julianday(time) <= julianday(?);', [ undefined, undefined ], [Function])
    at /Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/app.js:90:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at jsonParser (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:119:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at param (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at serveStatic (/Users/admin/Desktop/3100/a4/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT',
  __augmented: true
}

**What I am trying to do is, send data. This is what I have done:

```
    db.all(
        `SELECT * FROM users WHERE julianday(?) <= julianday(time) AND julianday(time) <= julianday(?);`, [add1.start,add1.end],function(err,rows){

        if (!err){
        console.log("Directly inside rows is: ",rows);
        res.send(rows);
        }
        else{
           res.send(err);
        }
    });

  res.end();
```

**

Comment: Yes it works now. Thanks so much Hey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.end` on the last line is called synchronously after `db.all` returns, but before the data base query call back is called (asynchronously). When the `db.all` callback is called, the response has already been ended.

Proposed solution: remove the `res.end()` statement.

(As discussed in answers to [this.question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29555290/5217142), `res.send` ends the response for you.)